# How to delete older rows with no change since previous row by ID

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a single table with three columns: `ID`, `Score`, and `Date`.

```
     Current Data
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Score      |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         3        |       05/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/15      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/30      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         5        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

```
     Desired Table
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Score      |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         3        |       05/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/15      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         2        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          123        |         1        |       04/05      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/30      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         5        |       04/20      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         4        |       04/10      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          456        |         6        |       04/01      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I'm trying to only show rows where the value has changed for the ID. Currently I'm using the below code, however, the code currently only groups the data which excludes when the value goes from `1` to `2` to `1` to `2` (I want to show all four rows/values but it only shows the latest `1` and `2`).

```
select * 
from Current_Table 
group by ID, Score
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your current/desired data as text, rather than images? Makes it much easier for people to copy/paste.

Comment: @JoshEller Like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LEAD()` analytical function:

```
select t."ID", t."Score", t."Date"
from (
  select t.*, lead(t."Score") over (partition by ID order by "Date") next
  from tablename t
) t
where t.next <> t."Score" or t.next is null
order by t."ID", t."Date" desc
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29f01/1).
Results:

```
ID  Score   Date
123 3       2020-05-01
123 2       2020-04-25
123 1       2020-04-15
123 2       2020-04-10
123 1       2020-04-05
456 6       2020-04-30
456 5       2020-04-20
456 4       2020-04-10
456 6       2020-04-01
```

Comment: What are the quotation marks for in all of this? Are those optional?

Comment: it's telling me invalid table name at the ```t.*``` part of row 3. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes they are optional when the table/column name is not a keyword or does not contain illegal characters. I used them in the demo fiddle and pasted them also here.

Comment: Did you include `t` as the alias of the table's name: `from tablename t`?

Comment: I got it to work but it gives me issues if I try to change the data (I need to merge it with other tables so the select portion of the query reads as this ```select t.id_number, 
       'X Category'                 AS Activity_Category,
       NULL                   AS activity_item,
       to_char(aa.ALMA_SCORE)    AS activity_group,
       max(aa.date_processed)      AS start_date,
       NULL                   AS stop_date``` instead of your ```select t."ID", t."Score", t."Date"``` line and now it gives me the ```ORA-00937: Not a single-group group function``` error

Comment: MAX(...) is invalid in this statement.

Comment: how so? (also sorry I missed that I changed the short-hand name for the table form "t" to "aa" on some of them - fixing it now in my previous comment.

Comment: MAX() is an aggregation function. Is there a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: no there isn't - honestly I'm pretty new to SQL and not sure if adding one would help or if we can just replace Max()

Comment: I don't know what you want to do so I can't tell. The code in this answer is about the question as you posted it.

Comment: But why does changing my ```Select``` line change if ```Max()``` is valid or invalid?

Comment: It is not valid to select columns from a table and arbitrary choose to aggregate on a single column.

Comment: if I needed to take the oldest version instead of the latest version of the repeated score, how would I do that? Would it be as simple as reversing the order in the order_by_clause after the partition somehow? Or by replacing ```next``` with ```prior```? I tried ```prior``` and that doesn't work

Comment: PRIOR is a reserved word in Oracle. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3824d97585e24d92c0013a448446c300